# why can't macports find make

Tags: port, path, mac-osx, make

I am trying to run macports like thus:

```
port install php5
```

When I do so, however, I get this error:

```
Error: Unable to open port: can't read "build.cmd": Failed to locate 'make' in path: '/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin' or at its MacPorts configuration time location, did you move it?
```

So I looked at my path:

```
declare -x PATH="/Developer/usr/bin:/opt/subversion/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/php5/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin"
```

and then looked to make sure make was in one of those dirs:

```
ls -l /Developer/usr/bin/make

$ lrwxr-xr-x 1 root admin 7 Aug  7 16:47 /Developer/usr/bin/make -> gnumake
```

And typing:

```
make
```

produces:

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

So I know that it's there.

But macports can't find it.  Any ideas?

G-Man

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make a symbolic link yourself:

`which make` (to be sure it's there)

`cd /usr/bin

ln -s /Developer/usr/bin/make make`

Answer (score 11):

One more thing - once you install xCode 4.3 from the OS X App Store, launch xCode, then go to Preferences -> Downloads and install "Command Line Tools".  Restart Terminal and you will be able to use Make.

Answer (score 8):

Have you upgraded the Mac OS since installing XCode?  System updates, major ones anyway like 10.5 to 10.6, may remove those programs from /usr/bin.  Download the latest Xcode and reinstall.  It should put them back.

Comment: yeah, as a matter of fact, at christmas I got snow leopard.  I'll try that and respond back in a bit.

Comment: That worked great!  Also had to reinstall ports according to this: http://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, worked for me too. Note: On OSX 10.7 Lion with XCode 4.1 downloaded from the App Store, you can re-install XCode by running the "Install Xcode.app" in /Applications again. Needed to trash /Developer before XCode would re-install successfully, though.